# How to quickly use jquery post to post files?

Tags: jquery, post, multipartform-data

I have this form and when upload it say undefined index 'banner'. I was able to get other input forms but the "file" is not working, I want something as simple as that javascript code.

```
<form id="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#" class="courses_create_form">
<input name="banner" type="file" class="form-control" id="banner">
<input name="banner" type="submit" class="form-control" value="upload">

</form>
```

Here is the jquery script handling it...

```
<script>
     $(document).on('submit', '.courses_create_form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var banner = $("#banner").val();


    $.post("uploads/process.php",
        {

            banner:banner,
            today: 'now'

        },
            function(response,status,Err){
            if(status=='error'){
// error
            }else if(status=='success'){
                $(".notify").html(response);
            }
        });
});
 </script>
```

Here is the process.php

```
<? // process.php
echo $_FILES['banner']['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Don't name both inputs the same

Comment: I think that you can find your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously#8758614)

Comment: Also note that `val()` doesn't get files, nor does `$.post` upload them

Comment: @charlietfl, you mark it as duplicate but the duplicate which of the comment or answer solves the problem..